# New Users and New Coders

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, new-users

Is there a specific area for new users that are new to coding where they can go and ask questions without being blocked for asking a question they may not have the answer to or isn't sure how to correctly ask a question. I know that there is a section for FAQ to try to explain how to ask a good question but for people who are learning and want to get the opinions of experienced coders, it can be hard to come here and ask a question. So again, is there a community that is open to helping new coders that may not always know how to ask the question they are trying to get an answer to?

Comment: What happened to your Stack Overflow profile?

Comment: One of the better received proposals for such a site: *[Create a separate, independent Advanced SO focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)* - *"...if Stack Overflow was split in two after all ... One site tightly under SO, Inc.'s control, open to users of all or most levels of experience and with an increasing* ***focus on helping, mentoring, nurturing, welcoming users of all levels*** *of experience"* (my emphasis)

Comment: Related: *[What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572)* and *[Are we being “elitist”? Is there something wrong with that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446)*

Answer (score 15):

I think what you are looking for is more of a "tutored" approach. Unfortunately that doesn't fit well with the Q&A format the SE network is built around. Perhaps venues such as Reddit, or old-school fora are a better fit for your needs.

On the other hand, if you have a problem with the code you've written you can definitely ask for help on SO. As long as you include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your current and desired outcome.

PS: Using a more friendly tone than the passive-aggressive tone you use on your profile might also prove useful.